# Filling all bitmap 1bpp with black

Tags: c, bitmap, fill

I try to fill all of my bitmap 1bpp with black, but there are still some pixels left out.

I wrote that code in C:

```
void fillBlack(void* img, int width, int height)
{

int i=0,j=0;

for(i=0;i<width;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<(height);j+=8)
    {
        *(char*)(img)=(*((char*)(img))^0xff);
        img++;
    }

}

}
```

where img is the pointer to the offset and all of the arguments are fine, especially width and height.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you think that you are abusing a little bit the use of parantheses !

Comment: I think you meant to do `for (j=0; ...`, not `for (j=k; ...`.

Comment: Need moar parentheses... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bitmap image consists of scanlines with pixels. A scanline is rounded up to the nearest word. Assuming 32 bits per word:

```
fillBlack(void *img, int width, int height)
{
  char *bmp = img;
  int i,j, scanlinebytes;

  scanlinebytes= ((width*1)+31) / 32 * 4;    // 1 = bits per pixel

  for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < scanlinebytes; j++) {
      *bmp++ = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 0 means black, your XOR is going to flip the value of any region. Say you have a 1 byte region with the binary value `00001000`:

```
black black black black white black black black
white white white white white white white white
-----------------------------------------------
white white white white black white white white
```

An equivalent and more efficient means of zeroing your region would be:

```
char *bmp = img;
memset(bmp, 0, width * (height / 8));
```

If 1 means black and 0 means white (for some weird reason):

```
char *bmp = img;
memset(bmp, 0xff, width * (height / 8));
```

In either case, you do not want to XOR the values. XOR flips non-matching values. You simply want to do an assignment. Therefore, if you do not have memset for some reason:

```
void 
fillBlack(void *img, int width, int height)
{
  char *bmp = img;
  int i=0,j=0;

  for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < height; j += 8) {
      *bmp++ = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

(Again, change the `*bmp++ = 0;` to `*bmp++ = 1;` if black is for some odd reason not 0 in your format.)

`memset(3)` is likely optimized on your system to do work on multiple bytes at a time, assuming you're running on a modern OS and have a CPU that supports this sort of thing.

Comment: this will not quite work (good idea though) because a .BMP image can have pad bytes at the end of each row of pixels.

Comment: The memset works fine but the way with 2 loops (for) still leaves white pixels. What are pad bytes?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a minimum set of code that demonstrates the problem as well as an input bitmap that illustrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
Each row of pixels must be a multiple of 4 bytes
suggest:

void fillBlack(void* img, int width, int height)
{
    char *pImage = img;
    int i=0;   // loop counter, image height in pixels
    int j=0;   // loop counter, image width in pixels
    int pad=0; // loop counter, pad bytes at end of each row of pixels

    for(i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            *pImage = 0x00;
            pImage++;       // step to next byte in row
        } // end for - width

        // there can be some filler bytes on the end of rows
        // as rows must be a multiple of 4 bytes

        for(pad=0; 0 != (width+pad)%4; pad++)
        {
            *pImage = 0x00;    // set pad byte
            pImage++;          // step by pad byte
        } // end for - pad bytes
    } // end for - height
} // end function: fillBlack
```

Comment: I'm afraid but it gives me segmentation fault. But when I change j++ into j+=8 it still lives white pixels.